# In 2 array sum question on leetcode and i keep getting inccorect answer in my last testcase of [3,3]. Instead of getting [0,1], i am getting [1,1]]

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int i;
        int j;
        int k=nums.length;
        int[] w =new int[2];
        for(i=0; i<k; i++)
        {
            int s=nums[i];
            for(j=0; j<k; j++)
            {
                int temp=0;
                int q=nums[j];
                temp=s+q;
                if(temp==target){
                    w[0]=i;
                    w[1]=j;
                }
                else{
                    temp=0;
                }
            }
        }
        return w ;
    }
}
```

This is my code, even in the first 2 testcases, i got the answer reversed, meaning instead of [0,1] i got [1,0]

Comment: Not sure of the details of the problem (looks like you need to find 2 numbers in an array that sum to a 3rd) but if the indexes have to be unique, change to `for (j = i + 1; j < k; j++)`

Comment: *even in the first 2 testcases,* What is the input of this testcases?

Comment: the test cases are [2,7,11,15] target 9, [3,2,4] target 6, [3,3] target 6. I am getting the reversed answer in first 2, meaning instead if [0,1] in first, i am getting [1,0]. but for the last i am getting straight up wrong one, [1,1]

Comment: ohk, got it, Johnny wrote the mistake i had made

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.